# Failed to external entity ".../htmlhelp.xsl"

Tags: visual-studio, wireshark, docbook, sourceforge, wireshark-dissector

I'm building a development version of Wireshark to create dissectors, following the tutorial found in their official documentation

I receive two warnings and four errors. The four errors seems to come from the fact [this link](http://docbook.sourceforge.net/release/xsl/current/htmlhelp/htmlhelp.xsl) cannot be loaded.  The errors are:

```
Build FAILED.
   "C:\Development\wsbuild64\Wireshark.sln" (default target) (1) ->
   "C:\Development\wsbuild64\docbook\developer_guide_chm.vcxproj.metaproj" (default target) (15) ->
   "C:\Development\wsbuild64\docbook\developer_guide_chm.vcxproj" (default target) (118) ->
   (CustomBuild target) -> 
     CUSTOMBUILD : warning : failed to load external entity "http://docbook.sourceforge.net/release/xsl/current/htmlhelp/htmlhelp.xsl" [C:\Development\wsbuild64\docbook\developer_guide_chm.vcxproj]


   "C:\Development\wsbuild64\Wireshark.sln" (default target) (1) ->
   "C:\Development\wsbuild64\docbook\user_guide_chm.vcxproj.metaproj" (default target) (65) ->
   "C:\Development\wsbuild64\docbook\user_guide_chm.vcxproj" (default target) (119) ->
     CUSTOMBUILD : warning : failed to load external entity "http://docbook.sourceforge.net/release/xsl/current/htmlhelp/htmlhelp.xsl" [C:\Development\wsbuild64\docbook\user_guide_chm.vcxproj]


   "C:\Development\wsbuild64\Wireshark.sln" (default target) (1) ->
   "C:\Development\wsbuild64\docbook\developer_guide_chm.vcxproj.metaproj" (default target) (15) ->
   "C:\Development\wsbuild64\docbook\developer_guide_chm.vcxproj" (default target) (118) ->
   (CustomBuild target) -> 
     CUSTOMBUILD : I/O error : Attempt to load network entity http://docbook.sourceforge.net/release/xsl/current/htmlhelp/htmlhelp.xsl [C:\Development\wsbuild64\docbook\developer_guide_chm.vcxproj]
     CUSTOMBUILD : compilation error : file /Development/wireshark/docbook/custom_layer_chm.xsl line 8 element import [C:\Development\wsbuild64\docbook\developer_guide_chm.vcxproj]


   "C:\Development\wsbuild64\Wireshark.sln" (default target) (1) ->
   "C:\Development\wsbuild64\docbook\user_guide_chm.vcxproj.metaproj" (default target) (65) ->
   "C:\Development\wsbuild64\docbook\user_guide_chm.vcxproj" (default target) (119) ->
     CUSTOMBUILD : I/O error : Attempt to load network entity http://docbook.sourceforge.net/release/xsl/current/htmlhelp/htmlhelp.xsl [C:\Development\wsbuild64\docbook\user_guide_chm.vcxproj]
     CUSTOMBUILD : compilation error : file /Development/wireshark/docbook/custom_layer_chm.xsl line 8 element import [C:\Development\wsbuild64\docbook\user_guide_chm.vcxproj]

2 Warning(s)
4 Error(s)
Time Elapsed 00:00:07.72
```

When I go to the URL directly, I am taken to a blank page. Going through the directory online I can go up to [here](http://docbook.sourceforge.net/release/xsl/current/), but clicking on "htmlhelp.xsl" brings me back to the blank page.

However, although the VS 2015 CMD says the build failed, an executable version Wireshark is built and I can use it with more or less full functionality.

My main issue is I kept on having errors building a C++ dissector (Lua dissectors work just fine) due to LNK errors. I was thinking, because the build is "incomplete", the issues could be arising from a missing file or such.

Comment: http://docbook.sourceforge.net/release/xsl/current/htmlhelp/htmlhelp.xsl is accessible for me. It looks OK (not a blank page).

Comment: @mzjn Thanks for the confirmation, it seems like it's the company's proxy. I was confused because other pages would load but not this one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this will help someone with similar issues.

It turns out the file could not be reached because of the company's proxy settings. I have been using IE and the file would not load.

However, when I used Mozilla Firefox, I was able to download the file. I changed the XSL import address to a local directory containing the downloaded file and the import errors were fixed.