# VS 2015: Compilation Error in file custom_layer_chm.xsl

Tags: visual-studio-2015, command-prompt, wireshark, docbook, wireshark-dissector

I've been working on creating a C++ Wireshark dissector. However, the development build fails, I've fixed a couple of errors but I still have two left. (I want to note that although it says the build failed, an executable development version of Wireshark is still created).

After building I get the following errors:

```
Build FAILED.

   "C:\Development\wsbuild64\Wireshark.sln" (default target) (1) ->
   "C:\Development\wsbuild64\docbook\developer_guide_chm.vcxproj.metaproj" (default target) (15) ->
   "C:\Development\wsbuild64\docbook\developer_guide_chm.vcxproj" (default target) (113) ->
   (CustomBuild target) -> 
     CUSTOMBUILD : compilation error : file /Development/wireshark/docbook/custom_layer_chm.xsl line 9 element import [C:\Development\wsbuild64\docbook\developer_guide_chm.vcxproj]


   "C:\Development\wsbuild64\Wireshark.sln" (default target) (1) ->
   "C:\Development\wsbuild64\docbook\user_guide_chm.vcxproj.metaproj" (default target) (65) ->
   "C:\Development\wsbuild64\docbook\user_guide_chm.vcxproj" (default target) (116) ->
     CUSTOMBUILD : compilation error : file /Development/wireshark/docbook/custom_layer_chm.xsl line 9 element import [C:\Development\wsbuild64\docbook\user_guide_chm.vcxproj]

0 Warning(s)
2 Error(s)
```

[Here is a link to my previous issue and solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39736181/failed-to-external-entity-htmlhelp-xsl/39775108#39775108)